# How can I delete a docker images by their tag <none> and repository <none>?

Tags: docker, docker-image

[tag  and repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5SLG.png)

I've tried various ways, but it still won't get deleted.

Comment: did you try docker system prune?  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Comment: You can delete the image by their image IDs which you can see from `docker images`

Answer (score 1):

Dangling Images are the images which are built without tag names or created when we overwrite them with a new image of the same name and tag.

You can filter them using -f or —filter flag.

```
docker images -f dangling=true
```

To delete those images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

or

```
  docker image prune
```

-q means quiet, which will print container id’s only